# Latent semantic classification

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, train, latent-semantic-analysis

How can I create a training data set for document classification using LSA? I have created a term-to-document matrix and have class labels also. I don't know whether to add these class labels in a term-document matrix or to create anther matrix. I don't know the exact steps to follow to create training data.

Answer (score 2):

You proceed the same way you would without LSA:

1. take some labeled corpus (e.g. [20 newsgroups](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/))
2. preprocess (remove stop words, stem, etc)
3. convert to the vector space model, weight by tf-idf
4. do LSA
5. build a classifier

So the only additional step here is the 4th one.

Here's an example for scikit learn adapted from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/examples/text/document_clustering.py):

```python
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', shuffle=True, random_state=42)
labels = dataset.target
true_k = np.unique(labels).shape[0]

hasher = HashingVectorizer(n_features=opts.n_features,
                           stop_words='english', non_negative=True,
                           norm=None, binary=False)
vectorizer = make_pipeline(hasher, TfidfTransformer())
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dataset.data)

svd = TruncatedSVD(true_k)
lsa = make_pipeline(svd, Normalizer(copy=False))

X = lsa.fit_transform(X)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X, labels)
```

Here's a list of useful links on how to work with textual data in scikit learn:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: I am not able to understand why you passed "true_k" i.e. labels to TruncatedSVD. It is supposed to take number of components and algorithm as arguments.

Comment: No particular reason

Comment: @AlexeyGrigorev are you sure this works? I don't see how `MultinomialNB` would work on negative values, and it looks like the output of the `lsa` step could certainly have negative values after the l2-norm is applied.

Comment: I copied that from the documentation. Now when you say it, I am not sure. Any other classifier would do, I suppose